# Changing div content with time

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html

I am trying to load a php file after a while by using ajax. What I am trying to do is kind of a  quiz. I want an image screen to be seen by user for 3 seconds and then the answer choices to be seen. I want to do this for 3 or 4 times in a row. For example;
1)The question image
after a few seconds 
2)Answer Choices
After click on an answer
3)Second question image
... and go on with this order.

I can do this with below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var content = [
  "<a href='resim1a.php'> link 1 </a>",
  "<a href='resim2a.php'> link 2 </a>",
  "insert html content"
];
var msgPtr = 0;
var stopAction = null;

function change() {
  var newMsg = content[msgPtr];
  document.getElementById('change').innerHTML = 'Message: '+msgPtr+'<p>'+newMsg;
  msgPtr++;  
  if(msgPtr==2)
  clearInterval(stopAction); 
}

function startFunction() { change();  stopAction = setInterval(change, 500); }
 window.onload = startFunction;
</script>

<div id="change" style="border:5px solid red;width:300px; height:200px;background-Color:yellow"> </div>
```

But, when this file is included by another file, this script does not work. How can I make it work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function load(thediv, thefile){
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
      xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
      xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject ('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
      document.getElementById(thediv).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
     }
     xmlhttp.open('GET', thefile , true);
     xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
```

The previous page script is above. I use this script with the below code:

```
<div id="anotherdiv" >
        <input type="image" onclick="load('anotherdiv' , 'include.php');"src="buton1.png">
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "included"? included with `<srcipt>`-tags, included via php, included later via ajax? The reason it probably doesn´t work is that the window is already loaded, so attaching startFunction to it will never be called.

Comment: I edited the question. Actually, you are right, the window is already loaded, so it is not loaded again. How can I find an alternative for my problem? thanks for your answer...

Comment: call it directly as just given answer suggests.

Comment: startFunction(); does not work unfortunately.. is there another way to call this function without onclick event?

Comment: maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you are expecting the window to fire onload event:

> window.onload = startFunction;

Window is loaded when the ajax is running, so why not call the function directly?

```
startFunction();
```

If you need some DOM elements before the script, just put the script below the DOM elements and the script will run after the DOM is ready.

Answer (score -1):

you need to remove `change();` from `function startFunction()`

here is the full example [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/sonusindhu/EnJzd/)

I hope it will help for you.

Comment: Simply "no". Why does he need to do that?

Comment: it works on own page when we remove change(); from function startFunction(). However it does not work again when it is loaded by another file...